# How to set an sms app as defualt app in android

Tags: android

I want to set my sms app as default . For this , I have followed [this tutorial](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html) and modified the xml file as follows :

```
<manifest>
    ...
    <application>
        <!-- BroadcastReceiver that listens for incoming SMS messages -->
        <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver"
                android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- BroadcastReceiver that listens for incoming MMS messages -->
        <receiver android:name=".MmsReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_DELIVER" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- Activity that allows the user to send new SMS/MMS messages -->
        <activity android:name=".ComposeSmsActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />                
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="sms" />
                <data android:scheme="smsto" />
                <data android:scheme="mms" />
                <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Service that delivers messages from the phone "quick response" -->
        <service android:name=".HeadlessSmsSendService"
                 android:permission="android.permission.SEND_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE"
                 android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="sms" />
                <data android:scheme="smsto" />
                <data android:scheme="mms" />
                <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

THe app is now set as default . But when any new sms is coming the app crashes . The logcat message is following :

```
10-04 12:49:17.293: E/AndroidRuntime(10911): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.commlink.smscheck.SmsReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.commlink.smscheck.SmsReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.commlink.smscheck-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.commlink.smscheck-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
10-04 12:49:17.293: E/AndroidRuntime(10911):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2581)
10-04 12:49:17.293: E/AndroidRuntime(10911):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:151)
10-04 12:49:17.293: E/AndroidRuntime(10911):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1418)
10-04 12:49:17.293: E/AndroidRuntime(10911):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
10-04 12:49:17.293: E/AndroidRuntime(10911):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
10-04 12:49:17.293: E/AndroidRuntime(10911):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5330)
10-04 12:49:17.293: E/AndroidRuntime(10911):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-04 12:49:17.293: E/AndroidRuntime(10911):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-04 12:49:17.293: E/AndroidRuntime(10911):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
10-04 12:49:17.293: E/AndroidRuntime(10911):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
10-04 12:49:17.293: E/AndroidRuntime(10911):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-04 12:49:17.293: E/AndroidRuntime(10911): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.commlink.smscheck.SmsReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.commlink.smscheck-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.commlink.smscheck-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
10-04 12:49:17.293: E/AndroidRuntime(10911):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
10-04 12:49:17.293: E/AndroidRuntime(10911):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
10-04 12:49:17.293: E/AndroidRuntime(10911):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
10-04 12:49:17.293: E/AndroidRuntime(10911):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2576)
10-04 12:49:17.293: E/AndroidRuntime(10911):    ... 10 more
```

Where is the error ? How can I solve this ?

Comment: The error is that class `com.commlink.smscheck.SmsReceiver` is not found. Are you sure to have such a class in your app?

Comment: No , I have no class named SmsReceiver .

Comment: Ok, then specify the correct class here `<receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver"`

Comment: you will need a Class which can receive broadcasts in package  com.commlink.smscheck  named  SmsReceiver as declared in your manifest